# What is the name of vertex with five edges?

Tags: mesh, vertices, retopology

I am interested in professional terminology for this kind of vertex - from which the five edges come.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are called Poles. Any vertex that is connected to 3, 5 or more edges is called a Pole.